# Таблица истиннотсти

Tags: javascript

```js
 function main() {
   var a, b, c;
   document.write("abc");
   document.write("<br>");
   for (a = 0; a < 2; ++a) {
     for (b = 0; b < 2; ++b) {
       for (c = 0; c < 2; ++c) {

         document.write(a, b, c + "\n");
         document.write("<br>");

       }
     }
   }
   return 0;
 }

 main();
```

как сделать так, чтобы рисовалась таблица с ячейками (строки,столбцы), и каждый элемент находился в ячейке

Comment: например собирать таблицу а не `<br>`

Comment: return 0 не обязательно

Comment: Личная просьба избегать использования document.write как устаревшего

Comment: @andreymal, но если очень хочется, то можно :)

Answer (score 2):

как вариант, нужное - добавить, не нужное - убрать

```js
function main() {
  var a, b, c;

  document.write("<table>");
  var color = 'style="border:1px solid #00f; padding:3px 9px"';
  document.write("<tr><td " + color + ">a</td><td " + color + ">b</td><td " + color + " >c</td></tr>");
  for (a = 0; a < 2; ++a) {
    for (b = 0; b < 2; ++b) {
      for (c = 0; c < 2; ++c) {
        document.write("<tr>");
        document.write("<td " + color + ">" + a + "</td>");
        document.write("<td " + color + ">" + b + "</td>");
        document.write("<td " + color + ">" + c + "</td>");
        document.write("</tr>");
      }
    }
  }
  document.write("</table>");
}

main();
```

Answer (score 2):

## ES6

```js
document.querySelector("tbody").innerHTML = Array(8).fill().map((x,i)=>("00"+i.toString(2)).slice(-3)).join``.replace(/(.)(.)(.)/g,'<tr><td>$1<td>$2<td>$3</tr>');
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>a<th>b<th>c</tr>
  <tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: не правильная табличка-то :)

Comment: @Grundy, теперь правильная. Недокопипаст)))

Comment: Минус за нечитаемый код. Вы все-таки новичку помогаете, а не в гольф играете.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function createTD(data) {
  var td = document.createElement('td');
  td.innerHTML = data;
  return td;
}

function createTH(data) {
  var td = document.createElement('th');
  td.innerHTML = data;
  return td;
}

function createTR(tds) {
  return tds.reduce(function(tr, td) {
    tr.appendChild(td);
    return tr;
  }, document.createElement('tr'))
}

function main() {
  var table = document.createElement('table');
  table.appendChild(createTR(['a', 'b', 'c'].map(createTH)));

  for (var i = 0; i < 1 << 3; i++) {
    table.appendChild(createTR([(i & 1 << 2) && 1, i & 1 << 1 && 1, i & 1].map(createTD)));
  }

  document.body.appendChild(table);
}

main();
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #09FF09;
  background-color: red;
  color: #09FF09;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: 'Arial Black';
}
```

Comment: да я так понимаю автору нужно было, чтобы ячейки выделялись?

Answer (score -1):

Использовать табличные тэги - оптимальный вариант.

```js
 function main() {
   document.write("<table>");
   var a, b, c;
   document.write("<tr>");
   document.write("<th>a</th><th>b</th><th>c</th>");
   document.write("<tr>");
   
   for (a = 0; a < 2; ++a) {
     for (b = 0; b < 2; ++b) {
       for (c = 0; c < 2; ++c) {
         document.write("<tr>");
         document.write("<td>" + a + "</td><td>" + b + "</td><td>" + c + "</td>");
         document.write("<tr>");
       }
     }
   }
   document.write("</table>");
   return 0;
 }

 main();
```